# How are the pytorch dimensions for linear layers calculated?

Tags: pytorch

In the [PyTorch tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/neural_networks_tutorial.html), the constructed network is

```
Net(
  (conv1): Conv2d(1, 6, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1))
  (conv2): Conv2d(6, 16, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1))
  (fc1): Linear(in_features=400, out_features=120, bias=True)
  (fc2): Linear(in_features=120, out_features=84, bias=True)
  (fc3): Linear(in_features=84, out_features=10, bias=True)
)
```

And used to process images with dimensions `1x32x32`. They mention, that the network cannot be used with images with a different size.

The two convolutional layers seem to allow for an arbitrary number of features, so the linear layers seem to be related to getting the `32x32` into into `10` final features.

I do not really understand, how the numbers `120` and `84` are chosen there and why the result matches with the input dimensions.

And when I try to construct a similar network, I actually get the problem with the dimension of the data.

When I for example use a simpler network:

```
Net(
  (conv1): Conv2d(3, 8, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1))
  (conv2): Conv2d(8, 16, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1))
  (fc1): Linear(in_features=400, out_features=3, bias=True)
)
```

for an input of the size `3x1200x800`, I get the error message:

```
RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [1 x 936144], m2: [400 x 3] at /pytorch/aten/src/TH/generic/THTensorMath.cpp:940
```

Where does the number `936144` come from and how do I need to design the network, such that the dimensions are matching?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The key step is between the last convolution and the first `Linear` block. `Conv2d` outputs a tensor of shape `[batch_size, n_features_conv, height, width]` whereas `Linear` expects `[batch_size, n_features_lin]`. To make the two align you need to "stack" the 3 dimensions `[n_features_conv, height, width]` into one `[n_features_lin]`. As follows, it must be that `n_features_lin == n_features_conv * height * width`. In the original code this "stacking" is achieved by

```
x = x.view(-1, self.num_flat_features(x))
```

and if you inspect `num_flat_features` it just computes this `n_features_conv * height * width` product. In other words, your first conv must have `num_flat_features(x)` input features, where `x` is the tensor retrieved from the preceding convolution. But we need to calculate this value ahead of time, so that we can initialize the network in the first place...

The calculation follows from inspecting the operations one by one.

1. input is 32x32
2. we do a 5x5 convolution without padding, so we lose 2 pixels at each side, we drop down to 28x28
3. we do maxpooling with receptive field of 2x2, we cut each dimension by half, down to 14x14
4. we do another 5x5 convolution without padding, we drop down to 10x10
5. we do another maxpooling, we drop down to 5x5

and this 5x5 is why in the tutorial you see `self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)`. It's `n_features_conv * height * width`, when starting from a 32x32 image. If you want to have a different input size, you have to redo the above calculation and adjust your first `Linear` layer accordingly.

For the further operations, it's just a chain of matrix multiplications (that's what `Linear` does). So the only rule is that the `n_features_out` of previous `Linear` matches `n_features_in` of the next one. Values 120 and 84 are entirely arbitrary, though they were probably chosen by the author such that the resulting network performs well.

Comment: I replaced the line with ``x.view(-1, x.size()[1:].numel())``, because I thought its shorter. I need to check, if this matches the number of features from the right layer.

Comment: It worked, when I tracked the size by substracting the padding and dividing by two for the pooling. Is there a best practice how to calculate this in ``__init__`` or ``forward`` or do you need to prepare each net by hand?

Comment: For sure you can write helper functions for a given class of architectures. That being said, you can also [entirely forgo](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6806.pdf) fully connected layers without losing too much. Myself, I don't have any patterns of my own because I don't work with classification